# Disable WinForms ProgressBar animation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there a possbility to disable animation of the progress bar?

I need it for some pocess which is paused and not running at the moment. An average user would think the process is running if the progress bar is being blinking.

The advice to create own progress bar control is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you talking about Vista's graphical effect? A marquee bar?

Comment: Yes. XP, Vista and W7 effect.

Comment: this may be relevant https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d223204c-24ab-4ca5-bb45-1400e3af2922/is-there-a-progress-bar-alternative-available-from-nuget-for-windows-7-that-sets-it-value-without?forum=csharpgeneral  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625930/cannot-get-progressbar-animation-with-code-progresschanged-not-called

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Forms ProgressBar: Easiest way to start/stop marquee?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312936/windows-forms-progressbar-easiest-way-to-start-stop-marquee)

Comment: @JimFell thanks for voting this question to close. However, if you read carefully you'll find that these questions are totally different. See the accepted answer in both of them, please.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the Vista progress bar's paused state, [like this](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Vista-ProgressBar.aspx):

```
// Assuming a Form1 with 3 ProgressBar controls
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SendMessage(progressBar2.Handle,
    0x400 + 16, //WM_USER + PBM_SETSTATE
    0x0003, //PBST_PAUSED
    0);

  SendMessage(progressBar3.Handle,
    0x400 + 16, //WM_USER + PBM_SETSTATE
    0x0002, //PBST_ERROR
    0);
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern uint SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd,
  uint Msg,
  uint wParam,
  uint lParam);
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you. That project is great: http://windowsformsaero.codeplex.com/

Comment: Just ran into this same issue myself. One question though: would this solution also work for software that will run on XP, or is it Vista/Win7 exclusively?

Comment: Link leads to a missing page. Better to copy & paste relevant info in an answer.

Comment: @SLaks Is there a way to get rid of the glow effect when it's green as well?

Answer (score 4):

My workaround was to use a Panel Control instead of ProgressBar. I changed BackColor, BorderStyle (to Fixed3D) and I manipulate its Width to display needed level of progress. I assumed that 100% of progress is equal to Width of the Form.

[image: Panel as a ProgressBar]

Answer (score 3):

The standard means of communicating to a user that an action is either paused or can't be accurately measured is to use the marquee display style.

```
progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
```

This style ignores the `Maximum` and `Value` properties and displays  a progress bar "segment" that continually moves across the progress bar and loops around (it doesn't fill the progress bar, it moves what looks like a section of the bar all the way across the control and around to the beginning again.)

Comment: Thanks. But I need MAximum and Value. The user need to see where the process was paused.

Comment: @Vasily: That's the only OS-independent procedure; if you're guaranteed Vista or 7, then SLak's answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is set the style on this control specifically to override the theme changes.  This [article](http://www.windows-tech.info/18/866def1f6059f141.php) gives you a bit of information.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedProgressbar.aspx looks good. But I doubt my boss would approve non-standard looking controls.

Answer (score -1):

You could override the OnPaint() of the progressbar. You don't actually need to rewrite the whole thing, you just have to inherit the progressbar and override OnPaint like this:

```
public class my_progress_bar : ProgressBar {
        public Brush brush;
        public my_progress_bar() {
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            brush = Brushes.ForestGreen;
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //base.OnPaint(e);
            Rectangle rectangle = e.ClipRectangle;
            rectangle.Width = (int)(rectangle.Width * ((double)Value / Maximum)) - 4;
            ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle);
            rectangle.Height = Height - 4;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 2, 2, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding `e.ClipRectangle`; this will not render correctly.  Also, you need a Vista-style bar.  Calling `ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalChunks` will make it somewhat better.

Comment: `e.ClipRectangle` is the area that needs to be repainted.  You should use `this.ClientRectangle`.

Comment: As I said in my question "The advice to create own progress bar control is not what I'm looking for."

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. OnPaint() is never called in a progressbar because Progressbars are painted by Windows (UxTheme.dll) but not by the .NET framework.

Answer (score -2):

Paste this as to code. This will rewrite the progress bar, it's also customizable to color.

```
public class CProgressBar : ProgressBar
{

public Color MyColor {
    get { return _color; }
    set {
        _color = value;
        MyBrush = new SolidBrush(_color);
        Invalidate();
    }
}

private Color _color = Color.Green;

public CProgressBar()
{
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
}

public int Value {
    get { return _value; }
    set {
        _value = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}

private int _value;

private SolidBrush MyBrush = new SolidBrush(_color);

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(MyBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width * (_value / Maximum), Height));
}
}
```

Comment: Btw it's working. If someone count this down, it means he's too cheap to try it himself.

Comment: I feel you, it is very rude to just downvote and not even say why. Although there are many issues with the code when using .Net 4.5: class needs to be partial, MyBrush cannot be initialized with non-static value, and nothing is painted in the end. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Width * (_value / Maximum) is always zero due to int conversion.