# SetProgress of Inno Setup TOutputProgressWizardPage doesn't update the bar immediatelly

Tags: progress-bar, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am using Inno Setup and I have created a progress page, set progress bar value and extract file:

```pascal
ProgressPage := CreateOutputProgressPage('Preparing installations', '');
ProgressPage.SetProgress(50, 100);
ProgressPage.Show();
try
  ProgressPage.Msg1Label.Caption := 'preparation ....';
  ExtractTemporaryFile(C_Myfile);

  ProgressPage.SetProgress(100, 100);
finally
  ProgressPage.Hide();
end;
```

But when I start  the installation the bar is on 0, when the file start extraction. How should the bar be set to 50?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Windows Vista, setting progress bar position starts a brief animation that moves the bar to the desired position. But as the application (the installer) freezes during the `ExtractTemporaryFile`, the animation does not happen.

There's a trick that avoids the animation. Just set the position little higher and move it back. Moving the position back happens without animation.
See [Disabling .NET progressbar animation when changing value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5332616/850848)

And you need to set the position only after `TOutputProgressWizardPage.Show`.

```pascal
ProgressPage.Show();
ProgressPage.SetProgress(51, 100);
ProgressPage.SetProgress(50, 100);
```

A related question:
[Inno Setup installation progress bar does not reach 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41579853/850848)