# Progress bar reaches maximum but animation does not complete

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, progress-bar

The Progress bar (Rollbar) does not complete before reaching the maximum, even though I have made an if statement that will only return it once complete.

[EDIT: I tried [David Heffernan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332616/disabling-net-progressbar-animation-when-changing-value) and now it almost reaches end but not quite.]

[What it looks like](https://i.imgur.com/EvBzZO6.gifv)

I know the if statement looks weird but that's how I interpreted the answer

```
        private void Bartimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Rollbar.Value == 1000)
            {
                Rollbar.Value = 1000;
                Rollbar.Increment(-1);
                Rollbar.Value = 0;
                Bartimer.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                Rollbar.Increment(1);
            }
        }

        private void Rollbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rollbar.Minimum = 0;
            Rollbar.Maximum = 1000;
            Bartimer.Start();
        }
```

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the animation speed or timer interval.

I have also approached this in different ways already by trying to stop the timer after the bar reaches 0 but nothing changes.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "does not complete" ? Are you saying the value never reaches 100? Or it reaches 100 but the progress bar isn't full? Or the progress bar disappears too soon? I don't understand. There is a lot of code not included in your example.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to set the `Step` property more than once...

Comment: *"The Progress bar (Rollbar) does not complete before reaching the maximum"* Isn't that by design? The maxiumum defines the completion.

Comment: @JohnWu What i mean is it reaches 100 but the bar isnt full, as you said.

Comment: I need it to fill up and reset once its done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides using a Timer, you can try to achieve it via Thread. Here is a demo maybe you can refer to. Using Thread.Sleep to simulate Timer.Interval.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Rollbar.Minimum = 0;
    Rollbar.Maximum = 1000;

    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart((delegate
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            Rollbar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Rollbar.Value = i; }));
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    })));
    thread.Start();
}
```

**Update: Using Task**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Rollbar.Minimum = 0;
    Rollbar.Maximum = 1000;

    var task = new Task(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            Rollbar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Rollbar.Value = i; }));
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    });
    task.Start();
    task.ContinueWith(t => Reset());
}

void Reset()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Rollbar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Rollbar.Value = 0; }));
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works, however i do not know how i would reset the progress bar after it reaches the maximum?

Comment: If you want to create a continuation when ProcessBar reaches the maximum. You can try `Task` with the method `Task.ContinueWith`. You can refer to my latest reply.