# Disable WinForms ProgressBar animation keeping the same green color

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I would like to disable WinForms ProgressBar animation. I found a good solution by SLaks for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834761/disable-winforms-progressbar-animation):

```
// Assuming a Form1 with 3 ProgressBar controls
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SendMessage(progressBar2.Handle,
  0x400 + 16, //WM_USER + PBM_SETSTATE
  0x0003, //PBST_PAUSED
  0);

 SendMessage(progressBar3.Handle,
   0x400 + 16, //WM_USER + PBM_SETSTATE
   0x0002, //PBST_ERROR
   0);
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern uint SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd,
  uint Msg,
  uint wParam,
  uint lParam);
```

But this code changes the green color to a very ugly yellow or red. How can I keep the original green color?

Comment: It cannot be disabled.  You'll have to make your own control.  There is a decent example in the MSDN article for ProgressBarRenderer.  A bit over the top, perhaps, you don't care about the chunks.

Comment: Thank you :-) It seems there is no easy way to solve this, and I will prepare my own control.