# backgroundWorker and connection to remote db Progress in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, database-connection, backgroundworker

I wish I could represent graphically connecting to my remote database, since it is not possible to know the exact connection duration, I thought that an endless progress control should do the job. Currently I am using WaitCursor which doesn't give me satisfaction.

When I use controls such as Progressbar, When I click to begin connection the progress is stopped since it is not used in a separate tread, so I tried to use the backgroundWorker, but have no idea on how to use it to database connection purpose.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        dbDataContext db;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
            db = new dbDataContext();

            var Users = from p in db.Users
                        where p.UserName == TxtUser.Text
                        select p;
            foreach (var record in Users)
            {
                Global._UserName = record.UserName;
                Global._UserID = record.ID;
            }
            label1.Text = "User ID = " + Global._UserID;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Endless progress controls suck.  Just my two cents.  Why don't you display a dancing unicorn instead?  Better yet, just tell the user "This might take a minute or two."

Comment: @Robert, Have you a dancing unicorn to rent :-)

Comment: @AlphaBird, Surely this method executes so quickly that there is hardly a need for progress indication? How many users do you have?

Comment: @KingCronus, Currently I have no idea on the number of users since this is resquested for a new project.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the length of time it will take, the usual technique is to display the Progress control in marquee mode.

```
myProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312936/windows-forms-progressbar-easiest-way-to-start-stop-marquee

Comment: Thank you KingCronus, I could run a progress control in marqee mode, now I need to ensure that it will run while connecting to database...

Comment: Erm... It should run as long as you don't dismiss it.

Comment: I tried it, **it doesn't run** untill database connection completed

Comment: Are you sure you are running in the background? If you are on the UI thread it may not animate until the calling method finishes execution.

Comment: Please how can I run it in the background ?

Comment: Alternatively, if you want a cheap and nasty way to test it, put a call to "Application.DoEvents()" in immediately after you set it to Marquee.

Comment: myProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;      
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();      
            db = new dbDataContext(); also animates after connection completion.

Comment: *Sigh*, where exactly are you calling the code? Can you edit the original question with some code? Otherwise I can't really help you further.