# Getting notified about program termination

Tags: c#

Please find below my piece of code. I crawled through Stack Overflow on how to get notified if a process is terminated and used the suggestions in my code as below(last 3 lines).

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();            
        //startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C rep_cmd "+textBox2.Text+" -text "+folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath+"\\";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
        if (process.HasExited == true)
           MessageBox.Show("Process done successfully!");            
    }
```

But, when I run the program, I get a runtime exception saying "No process is associated with this object". Clueless of how to rectify this.

Kindly help.

Comment: Your code doesn't indicate you called process.Start() to actually get the process going.

Comment: You are attempting to start a process, but you haven't started. please share the link to the SO question that you used

Comment: Hi David and Dhawalk... Sorry for the chaos! Please find the piece of code which I just edited.

Comment: I may be wrong, but shouldn't the code to start the process be: `process.Start();`?

Comment: Hi @ChrisLively! Made my program start statement as comment and tried process.Start(); But still, I could run the process but the message box is not displayed at the end. Any guess about the problem?

Comment: [Start.Process()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92699yzt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) has 3 overloaded constructors.

Comment: you should not assign process.StartInfo directly, better is using the return value of Process.Start

Comment: @user287107. Tried the same. But as I told earlier, I'm not getting the message box.

Comment: Thanks all for the help! It's perfect now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to spawn a parallel thread to check if the process exit in that parallel thread. the following method will do the trick. To ensure that you dont block the program, invoke it from a parallel thread

```
    public  void  CheckProc() 
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (process.HasExited == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Process done successfully!");
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Also go through 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Dhawalk. I did as you said. But still, the exception prevails. What shall be done?

Comment: oops! Sorry @Dhawalk. I commented my way of starting the process and used process.Start(); and it works out perfectly :) Thanks!

Comment: @Dhawalk.. I need another help yaar! Hope you could help me.. How do I add a Marquee progress bar until my process gets terminated?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312936/windows-forms-progressbar-easiest-way-to-start-stop-marquee