# modal indeterminate progress bars

Tags: c#, progress

I have a Windows app that basically calls other classes and within thise stored procedures and ultimately creates a csv file of a lot of info. I need a progress bar that just runs until its done so the user can see something is happening. I have scoured the internet and cant seem to get this to work. I just want the bar to start running on a button click. Why does this seem so difficult? The closest I got is just starting the bar in marquee but it wont "start" until after the object has been filled which does me no good, I need it to start while the object is being filled. This is being done in C#. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the long running task in a separate thread so that the UI can update while the task runs.

See [Windows Forms ProgressBar: Easiest way to start/stop marquee?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312936/windows-forms-progressbar-easiest-way-to-start-stop-marquee) for an example of setting this up.

Comment: The solution presented in your link is not working, I already have myProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee; in my code.