# Execution Timeout Expired when closing IDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, idatareader

I'm retrieving huge amount of data from SQL Server. Everything works fine but when I try to close IDataReader inside **using** statement

```
try
    {
      using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
       {
         con.Open();
         using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql_query, con))
         {
           command.CommandTimeout = 0;

           using (IDataReader rdr = new SqlCommand(sql_query, con).ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
            {
              dataTable = GetDataTableFromDataReader(rdr);
            }
             ....
```

I'm getting:
Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Would it be better to use something like **rdr = null**? Or is there another better solution how to close IDataReader?

Comment: I doubt that disposing the datareader causes the timeout. You can execute `GetDataTableFromDataReader` fully? Have you debugged?

Comment: Why you use `SequentialAccess` at all? Do you read huge binary data? This enables to read rows not at once but also as a stream, then you can use `GetBytes` to read the binary partially.

Comment: This works fine but falling into exception when it leaves last curly bracket.

Comment: Yes, SequentialAccess was advised on MSDN in case of huge data. Not binary data.

Comment: Not huge data but huge binary data. If you just select a huge amount of rows you should not use `SequentialAccess`

Comment: Still doesn't work with or without SequentialAccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there are timeout settings on both the connection and the command. You don't need to close or dispose manually inside a using block.

You are creating a second `SqlCommand` in the `using` block which does not have a timeout set. Change to:

```
using (IDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
{
    dataTable = GetDataTableFromDataReader(rdr);
}
```

Comment: I need to keep it there because
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                        if (showprogress) { Console.WriteLine("Downloading data from sql server and pushing into DataTable object"); }
                        da.Fill(dataTable);

Comment: I compared your solution and for 1e6 records takes 65200ms. Without using statement ends with rdr = null takes 38630ms. Seems it stucked on closing IDataReader.

Comment: Is it correct if just write:
IDataReader rdr = new SqlCommand(sql_query, con).ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);dataTable = GetDataTableFromDataReader(rdr); rdr = null;

Comment: Instead of using statement?

Comment: You don't have to use "using" blocks. If you do not then close and dispose the objects manually, not forgetting exception scenarios. In such cases it's usual to declare an object before the try-catch and dispose in the "finally" block (checking to see if exists and already disposed. You can also go an Async. This is Forms-based, but you'll get an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950113/using-executenonqueryasync-and-reporting-progress