# How to display progress on a progress bar using savefiledialog?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, progress-bar, savefiledialog

I want to display progress of saving a file using the "SaveFileDialog" and "Progress Bar" in a windows form. The file being saved is text file (rtf, txt, ...). This is what I use to save a file:

```
  private void Save()
    {
        if (TabControl.TabPages.Count != 0)
        {
            SaveFileDialog.FileName = TabControl.SelectedTab.Name;
            SaveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); //default path
            SaveFileDialog.Filter = "Rich Text Format|*.rtf";//Extensions
            SaveFileDialog.Title = "Save";

            if (SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (SaveFileDialog.FileName.Length > 0)
                {
                    GetCurrentDocument.SaveFile(SaveFileDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);//Stream Type for .rtf
                }
            }
            else if (SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                StatusBar.Text = "Saving Cancelled."; //Makes sure it doesn't crash on cancel
            }
        }
        else
        {
            StatusBar.Text = "Can't save. No tabs are detected.";
        }
    }
```

The GetCurrentDocument is this:

```
private RichTextBox GetCurrentDocument
    {
        get
        {
            return
              (RichTextBox)TabControl.SelectedTab.Controls["Body"];
        }
    }
```

Thus, SaveFile() is:

> RichTextBox.SaveFile Method: Saves the contents of the RichTextBox to a file.
>   [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile(v=vs.110).aspx)

Somehow I want to display the saving on the progress bar, or at least display a notice when the saving is finished (when the file is in the final location).

Comment: That completely depends on what `SaveFile()` does.

Comment: It's RichTextBox.SaveFile Method.

Comment: Unless your RichTextBox is gigantically long with text, saving should be a relatively short process.  And event if it does take a long time, you don't have access to an enumerator that tells you the saving progress.  Unknown long operations would use a marquee progress in those cases.  Just put `StatusBar.Text = "Save Completed."; after your SaveFile line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a progress bar as a Marquee style as you don't know how long it will take to save the file.
[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312936/windows-forms-progressbar-easiest-way-to-start-stop-marquee)

Answer (score 0):

what kinf of class is getcurrentdocument and what savefile method do. 
Could You use BackgroundWorker for save the file and open an progress bar in the ui waiting for a signal of the end of the workprocess.

[Howto](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjD_dWlwaLVAhWEChoKHUiHBkIQtwIIOjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DejiPWi14h-M&usg=AFQjCNGJ_8xNa1dvhKP1BePBnNlvt8Gwvg)

Write me if this solution it isn't enought.